# android socket Io freezing recyclerview scrolling

Tags: android, node.js, sockets, android-recyclerview

When android connect with socket io(node js) server but scrolling laggy but not with offline data.

```
IO.Options opts = new IO.Options();
opts.forceNew = true;
opts.reconnection = true;
opts.reconnectionAttempts = 3;
opts.reconnectionDelay = 200;
socket = IO.socket(BuildConfig.CHAT_URL, opts);
```

Comment: How often does it get triggered? Do you do diffing before setting recycler view items?

Comment: its because you are using force new to true also re connection to true! that will simply costs you. if possible try with force new and re connection to false

Comment: @DmitriiLeonov It's triggering on some devices

Comment: @JavaNerd does this options affects recyclerview scrolling?

Comment: @nishant yes offcourse just check it out with the options

Comment: @JavaNerd ok i will try and let you know. Thank you for help.

Comment: @JavaNerd I have tried the way you said but it's not working still scrolling is laggy.

Comment: then there might be some problem with the recyclerview adapter, please share some code to review

Comment: @JavaNerd I have used chatkit for ui part. and it's happening in some devices.